# Tomcat setup fails on Mac with 'Cannot find jni_md.h in /usr/bin/java/'

Tags: java, tomcat

I get the error below when I try running with ./configure (I am following steps in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/setup.html).

Error:
*** Java compilation tools ***

> checking for JDK os include directory... Cannot find jni_md.h in /usr/bin/java/
>   configure: error: You should retry --with-os-type=SUBDIR

The jni_md.h file is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A//Headers` so I used `./configure --with-os-type=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A//Headers`.

And I still got an error:

*** Java compilation tools ***

> configure: error: Not a directory: /usr/bin/java//System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A//Headers

What should I do here?

Comment: Why you are not using binary distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're merely using tomcat, you needn't build it, just [download a version](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi), unzip, set CATALINA_HOME, and hit $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start. The only reason I'd want to build it yourself is if I were a developer, instead of a mere user. Leave a comment if you have further problems.

Comment: I am doing this setup because I am trying to set this up so that I teach myself development in J2EE.
I have now set my JAVA_HOME to be /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/ and am still facing this issue.

@hd1 I tried running catalina.sh, but got this error:
apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Set permissions on catalina.sh to 755 and try again.